# Can't deploy public Docker hub image to Azure Container instances

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-instances

When deploying a new Container instance from the **jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest** image, using this simple test:

```
az container create -g Observabilty --name test --image jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

I get this error

```
(InaccessibleImage) The image 'jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest' in container group
'test' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential.
Code: InaccessibleImage
```

When I do it locally, it works fine, using for example:

```
docker pull jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
```

Anyone who can help me figure out why it does not work?

Deploying other public Docker Hub images to ACI works fine, like:

```
az container create -g Observabilty --name test2 --image grafana/grafana:latest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below approach to push public Docker hub image to **Azure Container Instances**.

I also getting same error when I tried to push the same image to **Azure Container Instances**.

[image]

As far I know, there is an issue with particular registry.

If you want to use same image, use below steps.

Step 1: Pull the same image to local as below.

```
docker pull jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
docker images
```

[image]

2. Change the **Tag** once you pull the image to local as below.

   ````
   docker tag jaegertracing/all-in-one venkatv1206/all-in-one:latest ```
   ````

> Note: **venkatv1206** is my docker registry username.

[image]

3. Publish same image to your personal **Docker Hub** as below.

   `docker push venkatv1206/all-in-one`
4. Once push image to Docker hub, verify the same in docker hub as below.

[image]

5. Now I tried to push same image to **Azure Container Instances** using **Azure CLI**, it got deployed successfully.

```
az container create -g <resourcegroupname> --name test --image venkatv1206/all-in-one:latest
```

[image]

6. When I check the same in Azure portal, it got created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work by using an older version of Jaeger (v1.41)

Comment: Ran into this same problem with --image registry.hub.docker.com/budibase/budibase-aas:latest - took care of it! Thanks for the workaround!

Comment: Ran into the same problem with another image. So, I couldn't deploy heartexlabs/label-studio:1.7.2 (exactly with the same error), but with 1.7.0 everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue my self, and it seems there is a but with latest on azure container instances, once I put the explicit tag ( when specified with -t on docker push) it worked.