# Cannot Deploy a public dockerhub imge to Azure Container Instances via portal

Tags: azure, containers, dockerhub

I have a docker container which is hosted publicly on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/crashserver/crash.server

I have tried creating an azure container instance via the portal, but every time I try I get the following message;

`The image 'crashserver/crash.server:latest' in container group 'testgroup' is not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential`.

I do not understand why I get this message as the container is public and doesn't require any credentials. I am using every default setting and still I don't have any luck.

**Other info**

- I seemingly can't use this container hosted on github either https://github.com/crashcloud/crash.server/pkgs/container/crash.server
- I found that I was able to use the grafna container on dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana/

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating container instance by taking public docker image as per your requirement. As shown in below image if i take image URL like below i am also getting error message and unable to create it.
[image]

Thanks to @Jineshkumar Patel for the [document](https://blog.jineshkumar.com/how-to-deploy-dockerhub-images-onto-docker-container-using-azure-container-instance) deploy docker hub images.

- By following this document then as shown in below image i have taken image URI (which starts from image name) as follows. Then i did not get any error message like before.
  [image]
- Then in Networking Enable DNS and take the name as Container name which taken earlier to avoid networking errors.
  [image]
- Then in advance select Microsoft managed key as key management.
  [image]
- Then click on review and create. As shown in below image copy the IP address after creation.
  [image]
- When I hit that IP address, as shown in image I am able to see that.
  [image]
  If you still facing any issues, you can refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75641421/cant-deploy-public-docker-hub-image-to-azure-container-instances) question and try in this way.